# Silverlight Authentication Cookie Expiration Detection

Tags: c#, web-services, silverlight

I've got a silverlight LOB application that requires a valid `FormsAuthentication` cookie when making calls to the service layer.  If a user idles for too long, that cookie expires, and they will need to log in again.

Can I either detect/check for the expiration of the login cookie in a reliable way at a global level (in Silverlight) and force log-out, or can I globally hook all service calls from one place (currently there are hundreds of calls across hundreds of files) in order to control a timer meant to detect when no calls to the server have been made for a time period beyond the cookie expiration length?

I'm open to other ideas as well, I'm not sure what else is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately we implemented a simple timed keep-alive call, it seemed to have the least impact in terms of work relative to its effectiveness.

Answer (score 0):

I have blogged on this some time ago:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/04/aspnet-forms-authentication-sharing-for.html